# Related db tables with zend framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

what would be the best way to get a result from a table using the table gateway component of zf2 and also get the related child result(s) of those?

mysql tables (arrow pointing to parent) :

article <- comment(s)

article(s) <-xref->author(s)

is join the only/best way to do this or do you guys have a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

ZF2 went back a step from providing full ORM functionalities like ZF1s `findDependentRowset()` or similar. This, iirc, was mostly due to the high complexity and bloatedness of the Zend\Db module.

You still have ways to make this happen, with the method you named yourself `join`, writing native queries, or to rely on the functionality of custom ORMs like Doctrine 2 which has a fairly great implementation in ZF2 nowadays.

You may want to consider [doctrine/DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)